# laravel 5.5 multiple controller inside one view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How to show TeamController@index and ProductController@index both show list of team and product inside one view main.blade.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you want to show two datasets on one page. Basically, it means you have to execute two controller methods but it's not necessary to follow each and everything that official documentation says.

For example, if Products belong to a team, you can execute only `TeamController@index` and show products as given below.

```
@foreach($teams as $team)
  @foreach($team->products as $product)
   {{ $product->name }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If no teams and products are two different entities and does not have any relation, you can just pass teams and products like this:

**TeamController.php**

```
public function index()
{
  $teams = Team::all();
  $products = Product::all(); // Don't forget to include 'use App\Product'

  return view('index',compact(['teams','products']);
}
```

and then you can show teams and products like this:

**index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($teams as $team)
  {{ $team->name }}
@endforeach

@foreach($products as $product)
  {{ $product->name }}
@endforeach
```

Getting information from two different models does not mean you have to execute two different controller functions.

Still, if you want to get data from two different controllers, you can setup **index.blade.php** and create two ajax requests that will get data from two different URLs (two different controller methods).

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: yep, this pretty much sums out what to do. should be accepted imo

Comment: My goal it to build SPA look like so what is the best way if I have more than 6 DifferentController@index to show inside my main.blade.php

Comment: Either you can include(use) 6 different Models in your controller and fire only one `GroupController@index` or create 6 ajax requests from your `main.blade.php` and fire 6 different `DifferentController@index`. I recommend the first method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show results from two controllers like that. Create a view that includes both the view that TeamController@index and ProductController@index return. be aware that both might be extending a layout which will probably try to load your page twice, so keep in mind to split the views into smaller components and include only those.

More info here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#creating-views